# CodeIgniter Looping Through Session User_Data

Tags: php, session, codeigniter

I am trying to create a method that return's an array of all CodeIgniter user_data for use in my library.

I cant seem to figure it out... is it possible loop through all CI session userdata and create another array?

```
private function load_session()
{
    $session = array();
    if($this->ci->session->user_data())
    {
        foreach($this-ci->session->user_data() as $row)
        {
            $session[] = $row;
        }       
    }
    return $session;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// Fetch all session data
$session = $this->ci->session->all_userdata();
```